# Como adicionar ou remover quantidade de itens em uma Lista em Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic, websql

Estou tentando adicionar e remover quantidade numa lista de produtos, como mostra a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta é a View desta tela:

```
     <ion-view view-title="Comprar Bebidas Adicionais" hide-nav-bar="false" >     

<ion-content delegate-handle="top" lazy-scroll  id="lista-bebidas" class="has-header lista-bebidass" ng-controller="exBebidasCtrl" >

            <ion-refresher pulling-text="Puxe para atualizar..."  on-refresh="doRefresh()"></ion-refresher>
            <ion-list class="card list">
                <div class="item item-input">
                    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
                    <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="Procurar" aria-label="filter bebidasextras" />
                </div>
            </ion-list>

              <div class='card product-card' ng-repeat='bebida in bebidasextras track by $index'>
                    <div class='item item-thumbnail-right product-item'>
<!--                          <img ng-src='{{product.images[0]}}' class='product-image' ion-product-image='product'> -->
                          <h3 class='product-title'>{{bebida.ad_bebida_titulo}}</h3>
<!--                          <p class='product-description'>{{product.description}}</p> -->



                          <i class='icon ion-plus-round icon-plus-round' mouse-down-up ng-click='changeQuantity(bebida.ad_bebida_cod_bebidas, bebida.ad_bebida_quantidade)'></i>
                             <span class='product-quantity'>{{bebida.ad_bebida_quantidade}}</span>
                          <i class='icon ion-minus-round icon-minus-round' mouse-down-up ng-click='changeQuantity(bebida.ad_bebida_cod_bebidas, bebida.ad_bebida_quantidade)'></i>


                              <span class='product-price'>R$ {{bebida.ad_bebida_valor}}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>


             <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="updateBebida()"> <!-- Chama para armazenar num WebSQL -->
                    Continuar o Pedido
             </button>             


  </ion-content>
```

Peguei um exemplo no Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/V1GEsL5IooR8MROuiAoc?p=preview E estou tentando adaptar, mas este exemplo é em formulário e o meu são botões e não funciona.

Este é meu Controller, com esta opção do Plunk:

```
     .controller("exBebidasCtrl", function($scope,$rootScope,$state,$ionicScrollDelegate,$http,$httpParamSerializer,$stateParams,$timeout,$ionicLoading,$ionicPopup,$ionicPopover,$ionicSlideBoxDelegate,$ionicHistory,ionicMaterialInk,ionicMaterialMotion, sharedCartService,CartServiceBebidasEx, $location, DBLocalAdBebidas){

    // VERIFICA SE HÁ BEBIDAS EXTRAS

    $scope.bebidasextras = [];       

    var promise = $http.get('http://nhac.esy.es/api_carrinho/lista_bebida_extra.php?json=restaurantes')
      .success(function(retorno) {
        console.log(retorno);      



        $scope.bebidasextras = retorno; // não precisa fazer retorno.data

            $scope.user = {
                bebidasextras: [$scope.bebidasextras[1]]
              };
              $scope.checkAll = function() {
                $scope.user.bebidasextras = angular.copy($scope.bebidasextras);
              };
              $scope.uncheckAll = function() {
                $scope.user.bebidasextras = [];
              };
              $scope.checkFirst = function() {
                $scope.user.bebidasextras = [];
                $scope.user.bebidasextras.push($scope.bebidasextras[0]);                
              };
              $scope.setToNull = function() {
                $scope.user.bebidasextras = null;
              };


    })
    .error(function(erro) {        
        console.log(erro);
    });    




    // MUDA A QUANTIDADE
    $scope.changeQuantity = function (productId, quantity) {
        var newItem = true;   
        console.log('este é o newitem ' + newItem);

        angular.forEach($scope.bebidasextras, function (value, index) {
            console.log(value + ': ' + index);
            console.log(value);
            console.log(index);

        if (value.ad_bebida_cod_bebidas === productId) {
            console.log('achou o id');  // tá ok
            console.log(productId);

//            console.log(productId);
//            remove if quantity 0 or null
//            $scope.bebidasextras[index].ad_bebida_quantidade = quantity;       
            console.log('imprime a quantidade:');
            console.log(quantity);
            console.log('imprimiu ai em cima');

            if (quantity === 0 || quantity === null) {
                console.log('quantidade é zero, valor nulos');
                $scope.bebidasextras.splice(index, 1);
            }else {
                console.log('quantidade > 0');  // tá ok
                $scope.bebidasextras[index].ad_bebida_quantidade = quantity;                
            }
            newItem = false; 
            console.log('Retorno não válido');
        }
        });
        if (newItem = true) {
            console.log('pega os dados');
            $scope.bebidasextras.push({ad_bebida_cod_bebidas: productId, ad_bebida_quantidade: quantity});
        }else {
            console.log('Retorno inválido');
        }
        };


        // PEGA BEBIDAS SELECIONADAS      
        $scope.updateBebida = function(){
            var p = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.bebidasextras.length; i++) {
               var item = $scope.bebidasextras[i];
                console.log(item);
               if ( item.selected) {
                p.push(item )  
               }

            }

            $scope.selectedItems = p;
             var item;

    //aqi vai percorrer todo o conteudo da vriavep p, poderia ate dar
    //uma otimaizada e deixar junto com o p.push(item), ai "economiza" um for
    for(var i in p){
        item = p[i];
        console.log(item);
        var titulo = p.filter(function(e) {
            return e.titulo_promo == item.ad_bebida_titulo
            conlole.log(titulo);
        })




        // TESTA SE GUARDA A BEBIDA SELECIONADA

        // INSERINDO DADOS LOCALMENTE
        DBLocal.localdb();

        DBLocal.db.transaction(function(res) {
            res.executeSql("INSERT INTO AD_BEBIDAS (nome_bebida_ad) VALUES(?);", [item.ad_bebida_titulo]);
        });
    }
}
})
```

Como vê é uma lista de produtos com dois botões de adicionar ou diminuir quantidade. E um terceiro botão de "Continuar pedido" que deve pegar todos os itens com quantidade > 0 e armazenar num localstorage (WebSQL na verdade).

Não estou sabendo como ir adicionando ou diminuindo itens desta lista.

Alguma idéia para me ajudar?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No evento** `ng-click='bebida.ad_bebida_quantidade = bebida.ad_bebida_quantidade + 1'`

**Mas troque o** `<i class='icon ion-plus-round icon-plus-round'></i>`

**por** `<button class="button button-small icon ion-plus-round">`

Comment: Ok, mas os botões estão okay, quero é pegar as informações e jogar num novo array.

Comment: Estou voltando só pra agradecer. Obrigado pelas ajudas! :))